# Android studio horizontal scroll view with images

Tags: java, android, xml

So im trying to implement a small gallery of images but what i have done so far has resulted in the images being spaced out from each other. I was wondering if anyone could suggest a better way of doing this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_qavel_nav"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#80CBC4"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.chiraag.qavel.QavelNav"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_qavel_nav"
>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplayDate"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplayDate"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#00796B"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/four_pillars"
           />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/marriotts_walk"
          />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/frankie_bennies"
           />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/blue_boar"
           />

    </LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: You can use a RecyclerView and set rotation to 90 degrees so it would grow horizontally or the same with a NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forced the padding and margin to 0 or try to put negatives values if you want to suppress any additional sapce between images. For example :

```
padding-bottom:-10dp;
```